# S.pyogenes binary fission rate/speed

Tags: microbiology, homework

For my Math IA (IB SL) I want to calculate the average amount of time that one viable *S.pyogenes* bacteria will need to create an ID50. I cannot find the average speed for the divison of any *Streptococcus* anywhere.

Comment: Hi @Jakub. Welcome to Biology S.E. I would highly recommend to take the tour (https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to know how a Stack Exchange site works. Also, you will earn a badge for reading the tour. As you will see, research effort prior to asking a question as well as using the correct tags will make sure that you can enjoy and use this site to its full extent.

Answer (score 1):

Growth rates are largely temperature-dependent. According to this study ([Growth rates of Streptococcus pyogenes and derived L form at various temperatures](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC277177/pdf/jbacter00445-0284.pdf)) the growth / doubling rates for *Streptococcus pyogenes* are as follows:

[image]